# How to make an If Then Else Regex conditional statement

Tags: regex

I am trying to make an If-Then-Else conditional statement in regular expressions.

The regex takes as input a string representing a filename.

Here are my test strings...

```
The Edge Of Seventeen 2016 720p.mp4
20180511 2314 - Film4 - Northern Soul.ts
20150526 2059 - BBC Four - We Need to Talk About Kevin.ts
```

In the first string, 2016 represents a year but in the other two strings 2314 and 2059 represent times in 24 hour clock format.

The filename should be retained unchanged if it matches this regex:

```
\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- .*?\.ts
```

Which I have tested and it works. It can match these test strings:

```
20180511 2314 - Film4 - Northern Soul.ts
20150526 2059 - BBC Four - We Need to Talk About Kevin.ts
```

If the filename does not match that first regex then this regex should be applied to it:

```
(.*[^ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-])[ _\.\(\)\[\]\-]+(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])([ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-]|[^0-9]$)?
```

This is a cleandatetime regexp that is used by Kodi to remove everything from a string AFTER a four digit number, if it exists, representing a date between 1900 and 2099. I have also tested this and it works.

Here is what I have tried to make the If-Then-Else Regex but it doesn't work:

I use this format --> (?(A)X|Y)

```
(?(\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- .*?\.ts)^.*$|(.*[^ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-])[ _\.\(\)\[\]\-]+(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])([ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-]|[^0-9]$)?)
```

This is A

```
\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- .*?\.ts
```

This is X

```
^.*$
```

This is Y

```
(.*[^ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-])[ _\.\(\)\[\]\-]+(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])([ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-]|[^0-9]$)?
```

This is the expected output...

**Test string:**
The Edge Of Seventeen 2016 720p.mp4
**Expected output:**
"The Edge Of Seventeen 2016 " (quotes only included to show that a trailing space can be left at the end)

**Test String:**
20180511 2314 - Film4 - Northern Soul.ts
**Expected output:**
20180511 2314 - Film4 - Northern Soul.ts

**Test String:**
20150526 2059 - BBC Four - We Need to Talk About Kevin.ts
**Expected output:**
20150526 2059 - BBC Four - We Need to Talk About Kevin.ts

I am looking for a solution entirely in regular expression syntax. Can someone help me to make it work please?

Cheers,

Flex

Comment: If you use PCRE, try https://regex101.com/r/LTtcJv/2

Comment: Magic! Thank you Wiktor.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually much easier, I posted the comment late at night :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a PCRE pattern like

```
^(?!\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- .*?\.ts$)(.*[^ _,.()\[\]-][ _.()\[\]-]+(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})(?:[ _,.()\[\]-]|[^0-9]$)?.*
```

Replace with `$1`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LTtcJv/4).

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- .*?\.ts$)` - the negative lookahead fails the match if the whole string matches

  - `\d{8} \d{4}` - 8 digits, space, 4 digits,  space
  - `-.*?- .*?`  - `-`, then any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, `-` and a space and then again 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `\.ts$` - `.ts` at the end of string
- `(.*[^ _,.()\[\]-][ _.()\[\]-]+(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})(?:[ _,.()\[\]-]|[^0-9]$)?.*`: an optional Group 1 and then the rest of the string:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `[^ _,.()\[\]-]` - a char other than
  - `[ _.()\[\]-]+` - 1+ spaces, `_`, `.`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]` or `-`
  - `(?:19|20)`  - `19` or `20`
  - `[0-9]{2}` - two digits
  - `(?:[ _,.()\[\]-]|[^0-9]$)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a space, `_`, `.`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]` or `-` or any char other than digit at the end of the string.
  - `.*[^ _,.()\[\]-][ _.()\[\]-]+(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})(?:[ _,.()\[\]-]|[^0-9]$`
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Now my requirements have changed a little.. I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405353/conditional-if-then-else-regex-statement) separately seeking help. It's a small modification of the challenge here that I think will require the (?(A)X|Y) approach. I would be grateful if you could help?

Answer (score -1):

Since you have mentioned that `A`, `X` and `Y` are tested and found working, and since there are only 2 patterns, I think this pattern will work (Python style):

```
pattern = "(.?(?=" + A + ")" + X + ")|(" + Y + ")"
```

which means:

```
(.?(?=A)X)|(Y)
```

### Explanation:

1. There are two groups - one for `X` and one for `Y`.
2. The group for capturing `X` starts with `.?` just to make the engine start moving and check if there is a part matching `X` ahead (a lookahead). If yes, it continues with matching `X` since it will encounter it after the lookahead block.
3. If in (2), the lookahead doesn't match, then the `|` (or) part, which is `Y` will take over. If that matches, you get a result. Else, no output.

(Sadly, the patterns for `A` and `Y` you posted were not working for me on Python, so I replaced them with my own for testing. Please do confirm if the pattern is working with the original ones.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my problem has now changed and I need to use PCRE. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405353/conditional-if-then-else-regex-statement) if you have time?