# Conditional If Then Else Regex statement

Tags: regex

This question follows on from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386155/how-to-make-an-if-then-else-regex-conditional-statement) about If-Then-Else Regular Expressions.

Because of how I phrased my problem in the other question solutions didn't use the (?(A)X|Y) syntax. But I think I need to use that approach.

Here is my problem re-phrased...

I need a regex that takes as input a string representing a filename.

Here are my test strings...

```
The Edge Of Seventeen 2016 720p.mp4
20180511 2314 - Film4 - Northern Soul.ts
20150526 2059 - BBC Four - We Need to Talk About Kevin.ts
```

If the filename matches this regex:

```
\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- .*?\.ts
```

Then this RegEx should be applied:

```
\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- ?(.*)\.ts
```

If the filename does not match that first regex then this regex should be applied to it:

```
(.*[^ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-])[ _\.\(\)\[\]\-]+(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])([ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-]|[^0-9]$)?
```

This is the expected output...

**Test string:**
The Edge Of Seventeen 2016 720p.mp4
**Expected output:**
"The Edge Of Seventeen 2016 " (quotes only included to show that a trailing space can be left at the end)

**Test String:**
20180511 2314 - Film4 - Northern Soul.ts
**Expected output:**
Northern Soul

**Test String:**
20150526 2059 - BBC Four - We Need to Talk About Kevin.ts
**Expected output:**
We Need to Talk About Kevin

Here is what I have tried to make the If-Then-Else Regex but it doesn't work:

I use this format --> (?(A)X|Y)

```
(?(\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- .*?\.ts)\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- ?(.*)\.ts|(.*[^ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-])[ _\.\(\)\[\]\-]+(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])([ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-]|[^0-9]$)?)
```

This is A

```
\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- .*?\.ts
```

This is X

```
\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- ?(.*)\.ts
```

This is Y

```
(.*[^ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-])[ _\.\(\)\[\]\-]+(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])([ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-]|[^0-9]$)?
```

I have tested the A, X and Y Regexes and they work individually but not when I put them together. Can someone help to piece them together using PCRE standard?

Cheers,

Flex

Comment: It is even simpler and you still misunderstand the *conditional construct*. You may just use an alternation: `\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- ?(.*)\.ts|(.*[^] _,.()[-])[] _.()[-]+(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])([] _,.()[-]|[^0-9]$)?`

Comment: Even simpler: `^\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- ?\K.*(?=\.ts$)|^.*[^][ _,.()-][][ _.()-]+(?:19|20)\d{2}(?!\d)`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/oZzNIV/1

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. If you want to make this into an answer I'll accept it and give another thumbs up but up to you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- ?\K.*(?=\.ts$)|^.*[^][ _,.()-][][ _.()-]+(?:19|20)\d{2}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZzNIV/1)

The pattern is a combination of two alternatives and as in any NFA regex the first alternative that matches "wins" and regex engine stops analyzing the the rest of alternatives on that level:

- `^\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- ?\K.*(?=\.ts$)` - matches

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\d{8} \d{4} -` - 8 digits, space, four digits, space and then `-`
  - `.*?` - 0+ chars other than line breaks as few as possible
  - `- ?` - `-` and an optional space
  - `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far in the memory buffer
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `(?=\.ts$)` - this positive lookahead requires `.ts` and end of string position immediately to the right of the current position.
- `|` - or, if the above alternative does not match, try

  - `^` - start of a string
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `[^][ _,.()-]` - a char other than `]`, `[`, space, `_`, `.`, `(`, `)` and `-` chars
  - `[][ _.()-]+` - 1+ `]`, `[`, space, `_`, `.`, `(`, `)` and `-` chars
  - `(?:19|20)`  - `19` or `20` substring
  - `\d{2}(?!\d)` - two digits, not followed with another digit.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my answer here -> [How to make an If Then Else Regex conditional statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386155/how-to-make-an-if-then-else-regex-conditional-statement/60391265#60391265), the same method is applicable still. I have tested it on the Java engine.

One difference that will help you is to name the groups that you are interested in the values of. Eg, I have rewritten the regexes below with named groups (small letter) `x` and `y`. Once the engine has completed the parsing, you can check for the value of match group `x` and then for group `y`, if there is nothing for group `x`.

Regex X: **`\d{8} \d{4} -.*?- ?(?<x>.*)\.ts`**

Regex Y: **`(?<y>(.*[^ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-])[ _\.\(\)\[\]\-]+(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]))([ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-]|[^0-9]$)?`**

You will have to choose the right group for `y` as I don't think I have done that part correctly.

Comment: Sree, thank you for once again supplying an answer. I don't mean to be rude but simply to feedback that both of your answers were too complicated for me to follow, I don't know really any regex! Also neither of your answers were complete or actually worked.

Comment: Oh! :-D Sorry, about that... I tested them on the Java engine only. And I welcome your feedback. It wasn't rude by any means. :)